# Receiving undeclared selector for private property

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I have this initializer in an assembly:

```
- (id<APBSearchWireframeInterface>)searchWireframe {

    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[APBSearchWireframe class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

        [definition injectProperty:@selector(searchViewController) with:[self searchViewController]];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(mapFromSearchInput) with:[[self mapAssembly] mapWireframe]];
    }];
}
```

The last line, when injecting `mapFromSearchInput` I receive a warning

```
undeclared selector 'mapFromSearchInput'
```

I have both properties in the private extension of `APBSearchWireframe`

```
@interface APBSearchWireframe()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) id<APBSearchView> searchViewController;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) id<APBMapFromSearchInput> mapFromSearchInput;

@end
```

And `mapWireframe` conforms to several interfaces

```
- (id<APBMapWireframeInterface, APBMapFromSearchInput>)mapWireframe;
```

If i move the property definition from the private extension to the .h the warning dissappears.Why am I getting the error for the second injection but no for the first one? I have all imports done correctly, and the app works fine, but this warning is really annoying...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured that:

- You're using forward declarations in your .h files (ie `@class Something`) and `#import` them in the .m?

If so and the error still occurs, then it seems the compiler is getting confused. You could:

- Pre-declare the selector using [sel_registerName](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/sel_registerName)
- Suppress this particular warning

Example:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"

... your code here ...

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: It works, I changed to [definition injectProperty:sel_registerName("mapFromSearchInput") with:[[self mapAssembly] mapWireframe]]; and the warning goes away. Thank you so much, and congrats on the framework, is great :D